# jsdoc make all underscore methods private

Tags: jsdoc

I have a large code base using jsdoc. We just noticed that a lot of private methods do not have the @private flag.

Is there a way to set up the config to see all methods that start with an underscore as private? I would really like to avoid having to go through hundreds of files to do it by hand.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer.
I installed this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdoc-autoprivate
which is unfortunately lacking in documentation. 
In my jsdoc.conf.json, under source, I had to add it as a plugin:

```
"plugins": [
  "node_modules/jsdoc-autoprivate/autoprivate.js"
]
```

And it works.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else found this question, jsdoc includes a plugin called `underscore` which does this nicely:

```js
"plugins": [
  "plugins/underscore.js"
]
```